# Infinite prefix-closed context-free languages contain an infinite regular subset

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

The Problem:

> Say that a language is prefix-closed if all prefixes of every string
> in the language are also in the language. Let C be an infinite,
> prefix-closed, context-free language. Show that C contains an infinite
> regular subset.

Can we show this by using Myhill-Nerode Theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a normal form grammer $G$ for an infinite prefix-closed $L$, examine the (almost) regular grammer $G'$ obtained by transforming rules of the form $A\rightarrow BC$ into $A\rightarrow B$. I leave it to you to show that $L(G')$ satisfies your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy solutions uses the pumping-lemma for context-free languages. Let $L$ be infinite, prefix closed and context free. Then there is an $l$ such that for all $z\in L$ with length at least $l$ there is a decomposition $uvwxy=z$, s.t. $vx$ has length $>0$, $vwx$ hat length $\leq l$ and $\forall i\geq 0: uv^iwx^iy\in L$ (actually, we don't need $l$ and just one $z$ and since $L$ is infinite, there is one).

Now take such a word $z$ and some decomposition. Then $uv^*$ and $uvwx^*$ are regular expression for subsets of $L$ (since $L$ is prefixed closed) and at least one of them generates an infinite language, because $x$ and $v$ cannot both be empty.

Using the Myhill-Nerode Theorem seems rather difficult:
Take the language $L=\{a^nb^m|m\leq n\}$. While $A=\{a\}^*=\{a^n| n\geq 0\}$ is an infinite regular subset of $L$, all the $a^i$ ($i\geq 0$) are pairwise inequivalent w.r.t. the Nerode relation of $L$. So we need an additional ingredient to show why we can collapse equivalence classes by not allowing certain suffixes (that is what taking a subset practically means for the Nerode relation).